# Can I remove the .html from .htacces just for a single page?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a website with the following links

- www.mydomain.com/NiceUrl1.html
- www.mydomain.com/**blog.html**
- www.mydomain.com/AnotherNiceUrl.html

What .htaccess rewrite rule, should I apply to achieve the following result?

- www.mydomain.com/NiceUrl1.html
- www.mydomain.com/**blog**
- www.mydomain.com/AnotherNiceUrl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog\.html$ /blog [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.html
```

That should work. The second line makes sure that any `blog.html` access gets a `301 - Moved Permanently` HTTP header, and therefore opens `/blog` automatically. The third line makes `/blog` point to `/blog.html` on the server.